# Questions about Future in Dart

Tags: asynchronous, dart, future

The tutorial on async programming [here](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures) talks about `async` `await`, but avoids discussing the `Future` API. I could find more information about the `Future` API [here](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#future), but still I have some questions. These tutorials made me raise some questions, ideally I should have placed one for each questions, but since they are small and related I preferred to ask them all in one place.

1. What triggers/starts a `Future` execution?

   From the text I can only conclude that once an `async` method returns the `Future` will be immediately triggered by the runtime.
2. What's the difference between `Future.wait()` and `Future.then().then().then()`?
3. Are `return await myFuture;` and `return myFuture` the same?

   The text says an `async` method will return an incomplete `Future` once it sees an `await` or a `return`.
4. The text says:

> Important: Async functions return Futures. If you don’t want your function to return a future, then use a different solution. For example, you might call an async function from your function.

How can we call an `async` function, get its return value, and not `await`, thus, not be an `async` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What triggers/starts a Future execution?

1. The code block for a `Future` is placed into the event queue, so it's executed when its turn in the event queue comes up. The [Flutter in Focus Futures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTS-ap9_aXc) video has some good visuals about how this works.

> What's the difference between Future.wait() and Future.then().then().then()?

2. They are different ways of handling multiple futures, but the differences are subtle. `Future.wait` handles errors slightly differently, and its values are returned as a list rather than in sequential code blocks, but in practice, the difference might not matter for your situation.

> Are `return await myFuture;` and `return myFuture` the same?

3. No. In the first instance, execution is paused at the await until the `Future` is processed in the event queue. In the second instance, the `Future` itself is returned to the caller and execution continues as the caller wishes (probably until the `Future` is given a chance to be handled).

   `await` is a language feature the essentially waits on the Future to complete at that point, whereas `return` simply returns the `Future` itself to the caller.

> How can we call an `async` function, get its return value, and not `await`, thus, not be an `async` function?

4. If you need the return value, then you'd call the `async` function and then use it's `Future` directly rather than use `await`. Here's a silly example:

```
Future<int> getAsyncInt() async {
  return 0;
}

void testAsync() {
  getAsyncInt().then((value) {
    print("Got an async int: $value");
  });
}
```

In the above example, you can see we use an async function, but `testAsync` does not await the value (rather uses a Future, so the end result is the same).

If you don't need the return value though, you can just call the `async` function directly though:

```
Future<int> getAsyncInt() async {
  return 0;
}

void testAsync() {
  getAsyncInt();
}
```

In this second case, in fact, `getAsyncInt()` will indeed be called, even though it's return value is ignored by the caller.

These are good questions, BTW, hope that helps. `async/await` can be rather mysterious, but thinking of them as event queues really helps to understand in the flow of execution IMHO.

Comment: 1 - My question is WHEN does the Future code gets placed into the Event queue? I imagine "when `await` is called" is the right answer, but what about when there's no `await`, like with the Future API?

Comment: 3 - So why the docs [here](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures) say `sync functions execute synchronously until the first await or return`?

Comment: 4 - Can I call an async funtion and block the code there, not awaiting for the event queue to pick it up later? IIRC C# has something like this for his `async``await`, where depending on how we call the `Task` (C# version of a `Future`) it will block, as if it was a synchronous function, or it will use the event queue and run it asynchronously.

Comment: To your first question: The creation of a Future puts that code block into the event queue. If that Future has a `then(...)` block attached to it, then that code gets pushed into the event queue after the completion of the first Future. `await` effectively says: "hey, take all of the code after me in this async function, make a Future out of it, and put it into the event queue to be run after the current Future we're awaiting for finishes".

Comment: "async functions execute synchronously until the first await or return", which is a change from Dart 1.x. In Dart 1.x, on calling an async function, the whole function was seen as a Future and executed later. In Dart 2.x, the function will be entered immediately, but then hand off control to the event loop upon an `await` or `return` statement.

Comment: "Can I call an async funtion and block the code there, not awaiting for the event queue to pick it up later?" No, because the code execution doesn't actually stop there, as the above answer notes: an async function is entered immediately and begins executing, and then it's up to that function then to decide when to hand things off to the event loop. Best you can do as the caller is to await an async function.

Comment: So I can't create a `Future` and return it for a client code to use it when it desires? Whenever I create a `Future` it will be automatically queued into the event loop queue and executed, so I can't create it to use later?

Comment: When you say "but then hand off control to the event loop upon an await or return statement.", does it means that the asynchronous job of `return` is to enqueue a `Future` that was created inside an `async` function? I am trying to understand the meaning of `return` into that documentation, what it does that's special to be included into the docs, right next to `await`.

Comment: If you need to return client code that is run at a specific time, you can return a function block, which can be executed whenever the caller chooses. And you can use various `Future` constructors (such as `delayed`) which will specify at which point into the future the `Future` should be processed in the event queue. But the point of a Future is not to hand off control over when it's executed. So no, you wouldn't return a Future for the client to then decide when to execute it (though the client can certainly decide which follow up Futures it might add using `then` on that Future).

Comment: And yes, you're exactly right: `return` in an async function returns a `Future`, which upon creation is added to the event queue. Even if there is not a single `await` in the function, the final return statement creates a Future with the return value (even a `Future<void>` if the function is otherwise of return type `void`). The great thing about `async` functions is that whole portions of the function can become `Future`s without complicated `Future` syntax, and it's the `await`s and `return`s that delineate how the code of an `async` function are broken up.

Comment: [Here's a sample](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#prefer-asyncawait-over-using-raw-futures) comparing async/await syntax with Future syntax; here you can clearly see how await/async essentially return Futures, but save you from the complicated Future/then syntax.

Comment: Thanks spenster, you have been very helpful and you truly have some deep insight into the dart language, I appreciate all the help and this last link showed me the next [topic](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-async-when-it-has-no-useful-effect) which illustrates other things I questioned before.